# Android virtual device has no network connection

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-machine

I am using the latest version of Android SDK in eclipse, but i don't have internet on my virtual device. I don't have any proxy. Android SDK is installed in Virtual Box With Windows 7.
Please can do you help me ?

Comment: Does your Virtual Box have internet?

Comment: change the latency of your emulator in **advanced settings** in **AVD manager**.

Comment: Yes i have internet in Virtual Box

Answer (score 0):

have you checked you have internet permissions in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: No I do not know how it's done , I'm a beginner about this program.

Comment: open your AndroidManifest.xml file, it should be at the left side of eclipse, in the project files.
at the top of the manifest, just before the <application> tag, add those two lines I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I have add permissions, but there is no change , I still do not have internet on my android devices.

Comment: I solved my problem by passing my virtual box connection by bridge and not nat , it works on a higher android 4.0, but still no internet connection on less than the android 4.0.